# Updating multiple docs with different values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My Node/Mongo db has a doc with the following data in a collection called 'prices':

```
 [ { _id: 1, price : 10 }, {_id: 2, price : 15 }, {_id: 3, price : 12 }]
```

...and so on. I now receive an updated doc from a remote site that that looks like this:

```
 [ { _id: 1, price : 12 }, {_id: 3, price : 15 }, { _id: 5, price: 20 } ] (some new some updated).
```

How can I change my data  to:

1. update exiting records
2. insert the new records.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change your data at all, you can tell MongoDB to perform an upsert

```
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    var p = prices[i];
    collection.update({_id: p._id}, {$set{price: p.price}}, {upsert:true, w:1}, function(err, result) {
        if (err != null) {
            console.log('Price updated!');
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: And for better performance for a large amount of updates, you can use [bulk updates](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/)